# Apoc.merge.relationship() creates duplicates in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc, cypher-3.1

I am trying to create relationship between two nodes using apoc.merge.relationship, but it creates two same relationships, which I can see by search. They both have same direction and everything is the same although from query it's obvious that `newLink.id` is identifier. I hope someone can show me what is wrong with my cypher query.

```
UNWIND [{ 
     color:'#82abd1', direction:'true', id:'q', index:0, linkType:'a', 
     source:'46166.a690c888-e3d5-41ed-8469-79a88cce8388', status:'approved',  
     target:'46163.a690c888-e3d5-41ed-8469-79a88cce8388', type:'Applies for', value:2 
}] AS newLink
    MATCH 
      (fNode:Node {id: newLink.source}),
      (sNode:Node {id: newLink.target})
    CALL apoc.merge.relationship(
      fNode, 
      'Label', 
      {id: newLink.id}, 
      apoc.map.clean(newLink, ['id','type'],[]), 
      sNode, 
      apoc.map.clean(newLink, ['id','type'],[])
    )
    YIELD rel
    RETURN DISTINCT 'true';
```

my search query is

```
MATCH ()-[rel]-() RETURN COUNT(rel)
```

Comment: You query looks right to me. Maybe something else created the additional relationship ? Did you try it again with 2 fresh nodes ?

Comment: I modified my question and below is the answer. You can edit if it's needed. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

My query was finding same relationships for both `(node1)-[rel]-(node2)` and for `(node2)-[rel]-(node1)`. So one way to avoid this situation is using ID(node1)>ID(node2), which compares nodes id given by neo4j.